# comparing list1 and list2, remove duplicate from list2 (not working with removeAll() )

Tags: java

I am trying to compare two lists where I want to check for duplicates. If list1 and list2 contains the same duplicate then the duplicate from list2 should be removed.

I've been able to solve the problem if I compare two .txt file or where list1 is a .txt file while list2 is hardcoded. Thus, if:

list1 contains stuff from a .txt file (which is like a template) and list2 is fetched from another place my code won't work.

Below you can see my code:

```
public static String removeLinesFromTemplate(String text) throws IOException{
    final List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    final List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();

    // New BufferedReader.
    final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("testing"));

    //Add all lines from the file testing to the arraylist.
    String row;
    while ((row = reader.readLine()) != null) {
       list.add(row.toLowerCase());
    }
    // Close it.
    reader.close();

    System.out.println(list);

    list2.add(text.toLowerCase());

    //If two lines matches between list2 and list, then that line will be removed from list2.
    list2.removeAll(list);

    System.out.println(list2);

    // Convert the list into string
    String listString = "";
    for (String s : list2){
        listString += s ;
    }

    return listString;
}
```

It seems like my list2.removeAll(list) won't work and remove the duplicates. Any ideas why, and how do I solve

I tried @SeniorJD's option3

```
String[] parts = text.split("\\s+");
for(String item : parts){
  list2.add(item.toLowerCase());
}
```

The problem still stays, example:
list1: 1 monkey, -------, (input of list1)
list2: 1 monkey, -------, asdf, (input of list2)

Issue here right now is that 1 monkey is not being removed, while "------" gets removed.

So the output of list2 is: 1 monkey, asdf,

Comment: `list` is empty in your example

Comment: You showed us the code, but the more important info is the content of the testing file and with what concrete argument you call your method.

Comment: What about debugging by your own?

Comment: And what you mean by duplicate? You mean it should remove duplicates inside list2 as in ["1","1"] or duplicate as in same values inside both lists?

Comment: @mavroprovato when I'm printing list it is not showing empty. The content from "testing" is being printed to list.

Comment: @SeniorJD Yes I have debugged it by my own but can't seem to find the problem.

Comment: @André ex; if list1 contains: monkey ============  and list2 contains: monkey ============ asdf. Then the result should be asdf since it does not contain in list1.

Comment: @user825023 Can you give an example of the variable "text" and of the file you are parsing ?

Comment: @demostene Can't actually give proper example of what the file and "text" contains because reasons. Check my comment above to André (assume list = testing.txt and list2 = text).

Comment: @user825023 debug your code, list contains multiple values because you are iterating reader and adding each line of file as value to list but you adding whole text string as value to list2 so list2 contains only one value actually your code is working fine as per your requirement, If list2 value matches with list value that is single line of your file then the value is removed from list2 hence list2 contains only one value after removing it returns empty only.

Comment: @user825023 Sorry my mistake

Answer (score 1):

Seems U don't understand how `String` and `Collections` work.

```
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>();

list1.add("a");
list1.add("b");

// #way1 - would not work
list2.add("a b c");
list2.removeAll(list1);

// #way2 - would work
list2.add("a");
list2.add("b");
list2.add("c");
list2.removeAll(list1);

// #way3 - would work as well
String text = "a b c";
String[] parts = text.split("\\s+");
for (String part: parts) {
    list2.add(part);
}
list2.removeAll(list1);
```

**Why?**

`String` is a set of chars, `List` is a set of Objects (in our example - String Objects). When U try `#way1`, the list2 looks for the equal object it already has. `"a b c"` not equals to `"a"`, or `"b"`. So it is not working as U expected. Try `#way2` and debug it, and learn the `Java Core` first.

Comment: So I tried your 3rd way and another example that I tried. Both of them does the same, for example;

list1: 1 monkey, ------, (the commas are added automatically)
list2: 1 monkey, ------, asdf, 

list2.removeAll(list) now removed the special character (ex "----" or "=====" etc). But it does not remove the "1 monkey" instead it is still there.

Comment: InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(text.getBytes());
final BufferedReader reader2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

    String row2;
    while((row2 = reader2.readLine()) != null){
      list2.add(row2.toLowerCase());
    }

Comment: 1. not here, 2. place the **simple code which describes the problem**, not the all of code u've written. if U need to test how String and Collection work, u MUST NOT use Streams and Readers in sample

Answer (score 0):

Your `list2` contains only one element(the whole text). The elements of `list` are lines from the parsed file. So in order for the removeAll to work you need to transform the the `text` variable into a list of lines.